# Windows Server 2008 shared folder requires login

Tags: windows-server-2008, network-share

I have configured a folder on my 2008 server to be shared with the 'Everyone'.  When I attempt to access this folder from another PC from Windows Explorer, for example, I am prompted for a userid and password.  Is there a way to prevent this?

TIA.

Answer (score 1):

'Everyone' means every one from the domain. You can use the Guest account if it is enabled. Also make sure the NTFS file system Permission allow 'Everyone' to read the folder/files.

There are 2 solutions:

1. Make sure the 2008 server and the PC are on the same domain and you are logged on as a domain user. This will pass the domain user credentials to the server and it will not ask for a username/password.
2. Enable anonymous access by modifying the GPO setting, "Network access: Shares that can be accessed anonymously". See http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc776860(WS.10).aspx